# Define a box by the coordinates of three points A, B and C

Tags: c, grid, coordinates, volume, box

The question ask define a new structure named point3d which contains three members **{x, y, z}** (all are floating-point
values) in 3D-plane coordinates.
Define a new structure named box which contains three points in 3D space {A, B, C}. Write a C program that creates a box (i.e. mybox) belonged to structure box above. Define the coordinates of three points A, B and C. The program should calculate **the volume of the given box.**

struct:

```
typedef struct{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}point3d;

typedef struct{
    point3d A;
    point3d B;
    point3d C;
}box;
```

I am using dot product to proof it a box. But how can you calculate the **height** and **width**? ( length calculated by magnitude Of vector)

```
void main(){
    box cord;
    point3d line1,line2;
    float pro1,pro2,pro3;
    int value;
    printf("Input coordinates A:");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&cord.A.x,&cord.A.y,&cord.A.z);
    printf("Input coordinates B:");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&cord.B.x,&cord.B.y,&cord.B.z);
    printf("Input coordinates C:");
    scanf("%f %f %f",&cord.C.x,&cord.C.y,&cord.C.z);
    line1.x=cord.B.x-cord.A.x;
    line1.y=cord.B.y-cord.A.y;
    line1.z=cord.B.z-cord.A.z;
    line2.x=cord.B.x-cord.C.x;
    line2.y=cord.B.y-cord.C.y;
    line2.z=cord.B.z-cord.C.z;
    pro1=line1.x*line2.x;
    pro2=line1.y*line2.y;
    pro3=line1.z*line2.z;
    value=prove_thebox(pro1,pro2,pro3);
    if(value!=-1) printf("This not a box");
    else if(value==-1){

    }
}

int prove_thebox(float x,float y,float z){
    float sum;
    sum=x+y+z;
    if (sum==0) return -1;
}
float box_volume(float x, float y,float z){

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ziwj.png)

Comment: Any three points in space lie within a plane, a plane is practically a box of 0 height and so 0 volume. Do you have more restrictions that require a box for the points? Orthogonality to an axis, plane or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You may align the `BC` edge along one of the axes (e.g. `Z` axis) and then find all the other vertices you need to calculate width and height like: `D = (B.x, A.y, A.z)`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a box with 3 coords (not points) with some assumptions similar you can define a recatangle with only 2 coords (under the assumption that one corner starts at 0,0).

So using the rectangle as an example you can define it for ex as (2, 3) meaning it has the following points for its corners: (0,0), (2,0), (0,3), (2,3).

For a box with 3 coords lets say (2,3,4) the following corners can be derived:

```
0,0,0
0,3,0
0,0,4
0,3,4
2,0,0
2,3,0
2,0,4
2,3,4
```

The volume of this box would be `2*3*4  = 24`